# how to disable system notifications in android using programming

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

While setting up the VPN connection in android phone, a system level notification with 'key' icon is generated by android system automatically. I am building an App which requires to set up a TUN interface internally but I am afraid of this notification which will be shown in notification bar by android system. I do not want android system to show up this notification to user.

Secondly a warning message "Attention" is also popped up while setting up a VPN connection. Again this message is also generated by android system.

I wanted my app to run quietly without showing any warning message and notification in notification bar. Any idea on how this thing can be achieved ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove or disable it without changing the ROM. It is an android feature.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try something like [How to cancel Android notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461743/how-to-cancel-android-notifications) or [How to properly clear all notification once clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13643045/how-to-properly-clear-all-notification-once-clicked) in two words - something like this:

```
// Clear all notification
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Xposed plugin `NotifyClean` to remove any notification, even the android system notify.

If you want to do it from source, viewing their source code may help.