# How clear all notifications of notification bar in Android 7.1?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-7.1-nougat

I want clear all notifications of notification bar and had made a separated class that extends [`NotificationListenerService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService)

```
package com.testando.teste;

import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;

public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
    }
}
```

and my manifest file is like this:

```
<application>

<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

 </application>
```

Then i want know why every time that a notification arrives, this not is removed?

Or then some one know some way of remove these notification without use of `NotificationListenerService` class, similar to "Clear All" button?

Comment: Are you sure you enabled the app access to notifications from within system settings?

Comment: @Pawel, then this can be the reason to nothing is working. How make this programatically?

Comment: You can only open settings activity like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32368604/9241978). It is impossible to grant this permission without user explicit action.

Comment: @Pawel,my app is unlocked to notifications and even so still not works. My last attempt was only [**this code**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676534/9672569) without nothing on manifest related to **Notifications**.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Clears notification tray messages
    public static void clearNotifications(Context context) {
        try{
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.cancelAll();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[AndroidHive](https://www.androidhive.info/) has a detail tutorial for Notifications with

Firebase Cloud Messaging

[This tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) is your reference.I hope this will help for you.

Comment: i need of a effect where i not need click over notification, want make equals to "Clear All" button. This is possible?

Comment: Form example, [**this way**](https://angularfirebase.com/images/native-ionic-fcm.gif)

Comment: yes, you can , it is work as "Clear All" button. You should try with code